# Invalid syntax error in python defining a function with PyScripter

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyscripter

I am trying to write this in PyScripter IDE:

```
def f(a):
    print a
```

[image]

and it says: `Syntax Error, Invalid syntax`. However if I try the same code in the Python Shell it is OK and I can see the result

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pyscripter by default uses the latest version of python *available* So You are probably using python 3 on pyscripter where `print` is a function so instead try:

```
def f(a):
    print(a)
```

And to set pyscripter to use python 2 add this to your pyscripter shortcut edit the `target` field to look like:

```
"path_2_PyScripter.exe" --PYTHON27
```